# where can you get the star on the menu in BOTW?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I need to beat ganon for good and don't want to beat him again. Can someone help me find the **star on the menu**?

Comment: What does this mean? Why would this help you accomplish what you want?

Comment: It will help me so I don't need to beat the game again.

Comment: I heard there was a star on the menu. Is it real?

Comment: I thought it would help so I don't need to defeat him again?

Answer (score 8):

Once you beat Ganon, there should be a Star on your save file when you choose a file to load.  That signifies that you have completed that task.  When you go back into the game, Ganon will still be undefeated since there is no way to actually continue the game once you beat Ganon.

See example here:

[image: Example save file with marked Star]

Comment: Might be worth mentioning there is no "End game" or "New Game"? Dunno if that is worth mentioning or not